# Comparing whether two trees are same or not?

Tags: python-3.x, tree, binary-tree

This is the question
https://leetcode.com/problems/same-tree/

Question:
Given the roots of two binary trees p and q, write a function to check if they are the same or not.
Two binary trees are considered the same if they are structurally identical, and the nodes have the same value.

I have used Python for solving this problem
This is my approach. Could you tell why it failed the given test case?
https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/661792014/

My approach:

```
#Definition for a binary tree node.
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

class Solution:
    def isSameTree(self, p: Optional[TreeNode], q: Optional[TreeNode]) -> bool:
        a = m = p
        b = n = q
        if p is None and q is None:
            return True
        elif p is None or q is None:
            return False
        
        while a:
            if a.val != b.val:
                return False
            
            if a.left:
                a = a.left
                if b.left:
                    b = b.left
                else:
                    return False
            else:
                if b.left:
                    return False
                else:
                    break
                
            
        while m:
            if m.val != n.val:
                return False

            if m.right:
                m = m.right
                if n.right:
                    n = n.right
                else:
                    return False
            else:
                if n.right:
                    return False
                else:
                    break

        return True
```

Comment: @JonSG could you check again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in your `while` loop, `m` will go all the way down via the same-side child (first loop: `left`, second loop `right`), but when it reaches the end, it will not backtrack and then look at all the opposite sided subtrees it had skipped along the way.

For example, take this tree:

```
            4
          /   \
         2     6
        / \   / \
       1   3 5   7
```

The first loop will check the left side (i.e. 4, 2 and 1), and the second loop will check the right side (i.e. 4, 6, 7), but there is no provision to go down the tree in a zig-zag way, so the nodes with 3 and 5 are never checked.

What you need here, is *recursion*. Solve the problem recursively for the left subtree and again recursively for the right subtree. If either returns that there is a difference, stop, and return False. If both calls give a positive result, and also the current node is equal, return True.

The solution (spoiler):

> `def isSameTree(self, p: Optional[TreeNode], q: Optional[TreeNode]) -> bool:
>      return bool(not p and not q     or
>                  p and q and p.val == q.val
>                          and self.isSameTree(p.left, q.left)
>                          and self.isSameTree(p.right, q.right))`